# Factoring a number in Java - Homework

Tags: java

As several other questions have asked on this forum, how would you go about finding the factors of a number.

Note: I have tried to understand what other people have written, please do not rehash already given answers

My code works as of right now but, for example the number 6 returns: 
6.0 factored by 1.0 is 6.000
6.0 factored by 2.0 is 3.000
6.0 factored by 3.0 is 2.000
6.0 factored by 4.0 is 1.500
6.0 factored by 5.0 is 1.200
6.0 factored by 6.0 is 1.000

Is there a way to remove all the decimal numbers?
I thought somehting about a "for" statement, but I don't really know how to use them.

Current Code:

```
public class Factoring {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    double input;
    double factor = 1;
    double factorNum;

    System.out.println("This application calculates every factor of a given number!"
            + "\nPlease enter a number: ");
    input = TextIO.getlnDouble();

    System.out.println("Original Number: " + input);

    while (input >= factor){
        factorNum = input / factor;

        System.out.print("\n" + input + " factored by " + factor + " is ");
        System.out.printf("%.3f", factorNum);
        factor++;
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use an `int` in place of `double`. When you use `double` or `float` you get the decimals.

So your this:

```
    double input;
    double factor = 1;
    double factorNum;
```

Should be:

```
    int input;
    int factor = 1;
    int factorNum;
```

**SSCCE**

```
public class Factoring {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int number = 15;
        int factorNumber = 1;

        while(factorNumber <= number){
            if(number % factorNumber == 0){
                System.out.println(factorNumber + " is a factor of " + number);
            }
            factorNumber ++;
        }
    }
}
```

**Result:**

```
1 is a factor of 15
3 is a factor of 15
5 is a factor of 15
15 is a factor of 15
```

**Explanation**

Consider dividing the number 15 by 2 just like you would in Math class.

15 = 2 * 7.5 + 0. Your quotient is: 7.5
In programming 7.5 and 7 are different. One is a *floating point* number
and the other is an *integer* or *whole number* as we call them.

To store floating point numbers, *float* or *double* datatypes are used. They 
preserve the numbers after the decimal places.
*int* and *long* on the other hand are for whole numbers and hence they do not keep 
the numbers after the decimal places. They do not round them up; they truncate it.

Try this:

```
double withDecimals = 7.5d;
int withoutDecimals = 7.5d;
```

and print them.
 See the difference ?

Comment: Can this implementation be modified to not check the odd numbers if the `number` is even? Similarly, not to check the even numbers if the number is odd. This would ensure that the `number/4` values are checked at the most.

Answer (score 0):

If the input number % by the factor is not equal to zero, then remove it from the list of factors. I'm assuming here that you're talking about the answers like "1.5", the ones that technically aren't factors of the input number.

Answer (score 0):

Use int and check for the remainder using %

```
int factor = 6;
int input = 1;

   while(input <= factor) {

       if(f % i == 0){

           System.out.println(i + " is a factor");

       }

   i++;

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

rather you use double for your number its better to change to integer..integer is for single number and double is for decimal number..

```
int input;
    int factor = 1;
    int factorNum;
```

and change from

```
System.out.printf("%.3f", factorNum);
```

to

```
System.out.printf("%.0f", factorNum);
```

Answer (score 0):

I stored the factors in ArrayList

```
          int s = /* Your number or get from user */;
    ArrayList<Integer>integers = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 1 ; i <= s ; i++){
        if(s%i == 0){
         integers.add(i);
           /* just for printing the factors */ System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
```